# Can I use DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder and LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder together in Netty?

Tags: java, netty, backend

I have a netty server run which should support two protocol
One is heartbeat, the protocol is

`1. client send "PING@" ----> server
2. sever response "PONG@" ---> client`

the other one is LengthFieldBased, can I handle it at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You may use DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder with maxFrameLength.

https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.html